# Replace old content with new in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am developing video Player in which XML is my playlist. Here is code:

```
$crxml=file_get_contents('http://spoti.com/latest.xml/?lang=en');    
   $rss=new SimpleXMLElement($crxml);
  $playlistitem=1;
foreach($rss->channel->item as $post)

if($playlistitem<=8)

echo '<ul>';
echo '<li class="xtitle">'.$post->title.'</li>';
echo '<li class="xdesc">'.$post->description.'</li>';    
$dc=$post->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
echo '<li class="xthumb">'.$dc->thumbnail->attributes()->url.'</li>';
echo '<li class="xpreview">'.$dc->thumbnail->attributes()->url.'</li>'; 
echo '<li class="xsources_mp4">'.$dc->content->attributes()->url.'</li>';
$dc->content->attributes()->url=preg_replace('/.mp4/','.webm',$dc->content-attributes()->url);
 echo '<li class="xsources_webm">'.$dc->content->attributes()->url.'</li>';
 echo '</ul>';
$playlistitem++;
```

I want to replace the old content with new content when user click on Language all the entries replace with new entries

Comment: Unless you're doing a traditional round-trip form submission system, you'll need some Javascript to rewrite the tag contents.

Comment: Well, what is not working - and what do you really want to have as result. Like swapping language and the old lines to fade away?

Comment: @MaxAllan Yes when user chnage the language  from Select option then language changes automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example

```
if(isset($_POST["lang"]))
    {
       $lang = $_POST["lang"];
    } else {
       $lang = "eng";
    }
$crxml=file_get_contents('http://spoti.com/latest.xml/?lang='.$lang);    
$rss=new SimpleXMLElement($crxml);
$playlistitem=1;

foreach($rss->channel->item as $post) {
    if($playlistitem<=8) {
        echo '<ul id="playlist">';
        echo '<li class="xtitle">'.$post->title.'</li>';
        echo '<li class="xdesc">'.$post->description.'</li>';    
        $dc=$post->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
        echo '<li class="xthumb">'.$dc->thumbnail->attributes()->url.'</li>';
        echo '<li class="xpreview">'.$dc->thumbnail->attributes()->url.'</li>';
        echo '<li class="xsources_mp4">'.$dc->content->attributes()->url.'</li>';
        $dc->content->attributes()->url=preg_replace('/.mp4/','.webm',$dc->content-attributes()->url);
        echo '<li class="xsources_webm">'.$dc->content->attributes()->url.'</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
        $playlistitem++;
    }
}
```

Then in jQuery on the page there is a selectbox with lanuages called #langSelect

```
$('#langSelect').change( function() {
    var langSelected = $(this).val();

    $("#playlist").load("<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?uid=".time(); ?> #playlist", {lang: langSelected});
});
```

---

To debug try using this:

```
$('#lang').change( function() {
    var langSelected = $(this).val();
    alert('Selected language: '+langSelected);
    var url = '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?uid=".time(); ?>';
    alert('Ajax POST URL is: '+ url);
    $("#playlist").load(url+" #playlist", {lang: langSelected}, function(response, status, xhr) {
            alert(status);
            alert(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: code is correct but not working as nothing shown in playlist when I change the language

Comment: Hmmm can you see it loading the page (through firebug/fiddler)? Im thinking it might be an cache issue, so it might help adding current time to the request url. Updated code with a timestamp.

Comment: -Yeah I seen page is not loading also nothing happen when I change the selection of opstions

Comment: You have an ID on the selectbox with `#langSelect` right? Also check that the PHP in the ajax call is being outputted correctly.. maybe paste the output you get, then i might be able to spot the error :)

Comment: -I add the code above,you can check and find the error on it.It will great help from you.Thanks a lot for helping me out

Comment: Updated with a debug test code, try inserting that, it should alert all steps so we can see where it fails :)

Comment: Johannese:it work fully but now things it load full php again it not overloading on same xplaylist

Comment: Its because you create the playlist TWO times in your php. Atleast you pasted two different ones in you code. One where you test if $_POST["lang"]) is set, and in a switch statement :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10060/discussion-between-arpit-srivastava-and-marco-johannesen)

Comment: -Css not indent properly why is it so?all the thing are dispersed when ajax call in playlist option